# Отправка определенного текста в текстовой документ

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как или вернее, какие команды должна совершать программа, чтобы определенный текст был добавлен в текстовый документ с новой строки?

Текстовый документ будет находиться по адресу http://******.ru/123.txt

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Как именно и куда будет добавляться текст?

Comment: В текстовый документ http://**.ru/123.txt должен добавляться текст (любой, задаваться будет). Какие команды должна выполнять программа?

Comment: А также необходимо уточнить, файл, в который Вы хотите записать, находится на том же сервере или на другом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ммм..вы понимаете, что вопрос задан не полностью? Смотрите, вот так правильно, как пример: "Я хочу, чтобы из поля ввода, расположенного на моей вэб-странице, по нажатии кнопки(также расположенной на моей странице) весь введённый текст был добавлен в новую строку в существующий файл по адресу ХХХ. Необходимо использовать PHP(JavaScript). Какой код я должен написать?"
Чувствуете разницу?

Если также подробно сложно—опишите максимально подробно простыми словами.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляйте в конец каждой строки "\n".